# iOS Swift Core Data Counting Child Entities

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Good morning,

I have a parent entity, lets call it Neighborhood, which logically possesses child entities, Houses. In my Core Data model, these entities are not linked via a relationship (yet). Additionally, the actual relationship between the entities is managed by a server side application that is the system of record for the foreign key relationships and all data. In the schemas below you will notice that there are id and foreign_id properties. These values are provided by a server.

Neighborhood has the following schema:

```
id int32
name string
```

House has the following schema:

```
id int32
neighborhood_id int32
address string
has_completed_build boolean
```

If I have 5,000 neighborhoods in the local database with 20 houses in each, how can I efficiently return all 5,000 neighborhoods with a count of the child houses that `has_completed_build = true` and `has_completed_build = false`? I don't think I can even link these two entities through a relationship because that relationship is defined by keys external to ios. Can this be managed through a fetched property?

Right now I am looping through each neighborhood and querying on each row for a count of the children by `House.neighborhood_id = Neighborhood.id`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to (or I agree in this case, can't) use Core Data relationships, why not look at sqlite?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes... not a bad idea. My decision to use core data was ill conceived as I did not understand how the relationships were managed. My assumption was that with Core Data one could define the FK relationships - this is how most ORMs work.

Comment: CoreData can persist to SQLite and has relationships but it isn't an RDBMS - you can't really join, for example which is what it sounds like you need

Comment: Switching at this point will be fun :-D Need to create migration and all that jazz. So, as it stands, Core Data will not support what I am hoping for.

Comment: You could do a query on `Houses`, grouped by `neighbourhood_id` and `has_completed_build`, to get the relevant counts, and then fetch `Neighborhoods` to find the corresponding name.

Comment: @pbasdf Ah, yes, interesting approach. That would bring me down to two queries. One to get the counts grouped by id and the boolean and the other to bring back the neighborhoods. If you have an example of how to do grouping with Core Data queries, please submit an answer with your recommendation. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per comments, you could do a fetch grouped by `neighborhood_id` and `has_completed_build` to get the counts, and then a separate fetch to get the name for the `neighborhood_id`.  Something like this:

```
    let fetch = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "House")
    let countExpression = NSExpression(format: "count:(id)")
    let countED = NSExpressionDescription()
    countED.expression = countExpression
    countED.name = "countOfHouses"
    countED.expressionResultType = .DoubleAttributeType
    fetch.propertiesToFetch = ["neighborhood_id", "has_completed_build", countED]
    fetch.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
    fetch.propertiesToGroupBy = ["neighborhood_id", "has_completed_build"]
    let houseCounts = managedObjectContext?.executeFetchRequest(fetch, error: nil)
```

This will get you an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary having keys "neighborhood_id", "has_completed_build" and "countOfHouses".  I'm afraid my Swift skills aren't up to finding an efficient way to lookup values from this structure (effectively to do the join).  I will think on it some more, but hope this gets you started in the mean time.

Comment: Excellent. I will test this out and if it works I will mark it as the answer. Cheers.

Comment: This worked very well. And for completeness, you can filter the resulting array of dictionaries in swift with myArray.filter() { $0["has_completed_build"]?.boolValue != nil && $0["has_completed_build"]?.boolValue! == true };